# Rendered video randomly twice as fast as audio (preview looks normal)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

A very strange thing is happening to me in blender. I recorded footage from cca 10 years old camera (can't tell you the type, don't remember). The footage was 25fps, original dimension 1440x1080. I set up the blender environment according to youtube video called [*1 - Blender Video Editing (Setup Defaults)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjTn8GsRk48&index=2&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) by *Mikeycal Meyers* and started inserting my clips.

As the tutorial said, I was supposed to match the dimensions and fps of the original with the settings in Blender. But when I changed the Blenders Preset resolution of 1920x1080 to my needed 1440x1080, the video got squeezed from right and left, leaving the picture squeezed and therefore useless. So I changed it back, hoping it wouldn't matter (but it may affect the problem I'm about to describe).

I had footage that was all taken from one camera under the same settings. When I took pieces of the recording and cut them in Blender, after rendering, in a few of these cuts the video is twice as fast as the audio. The rest is fine. Later, I deleted and inserted the "wrong" pieces again. The strangest thing is that one day it rendered fine, and a few days later the latter clip got rendered wrong again.

You can see here:

- everything at the right speed - http://www.filedropper.com/8168-9085
- second cut is wrong - http://www.filedropper.com/8700-9921

Could you tell what went wrong from this?

Would be very grateful for a solution, this has taken many hours already...

System Information:
RHEL 7.1 (Maipo).
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)

Blender Version: blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64

Comment: More important is the media information. What is the source media? Frame rate, frame size, CODEC etc. Blender cannot easily mix different frame rates on the timeline (that's why video speeds up). All media should match the "Project" frame rate. When you changed to 1440 x 1080 you either made a square frame or an anamorphic (stretched) frame. If it needs to be stretched you must alter the aspect in the project settings. If you have used a preset dimensions in the project settings then it may have altered the frame rate as well as the dimensions.